Combining legends from parameterized plots and positioning these to not exceed frame width
I have combined five different plots based on a parameter each with its own legend. Now, I want to position legends below the combined plot. The following is one of the sample codes:
 p = 7.
q = 10.
r = 10.
c = 10.
Vl0 = 200.
Qlf = 10.
eglf = 0.7
egl0 = 0.
A == Fn1(p,q,r,c)
B == Fn2(p,q,r,c)
C == Fn3(p,q,r,c)
b = 200.
A1 == r + Qlf
B1 == p
B1/A1 == p/(r + Qlf)

sDim = Plot[
   Evaluate[{Vl0 + Fn(p,q,r,c)
        )*x
     }], {x, 0, 20000}, Frame -> True, AxesLabel -> {Time, Vl}, 
   FrameLabel -> { Style["x", Italic], 
     Style["z", Italic]}, Evaluated -> True,
    PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"q=10 (A)"}, LegendMarkers -> None, 
      LegendLayout -> {"Row", 3}], Below], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}];
sVl1 = With[{p = 7., q = 10., r = 10., c = 10.}, 
  NDSolve[{z'[x] == Fn4, 
    y'[x] == Fn5(p,q,r,c,x,z) 
    z[0] == 200., y[0] == 0.}, {z, y}, {x, 0, 20000}]]
sVl2 = Plot[Evaluate[{z[x]} /. sVl1], {x, 0, 20000}, Frame -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {Time, Vl}, 
   FrameLabel -> { Style["x", Italic], 
     Style["z", Italic]}, Evaluated -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"q=10 (N)"}, LegendMarkers -> None, 
      LegendLayout -> {"Row", 3}], Below], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.025], Blue, Dotted}];
q10Vl = Show[sVl2, sDim]

The type of plot, I am getting is;

I want the legends to not exceed the boundaries of the plot but rather to be rearranged automatically below the plot in two/three rows accordingly.
Please help me with this.
Thanks.

Try LegendLayout -> {"Row",3}.

As I have 5 codes, do I have to modify in all codes? and then combine plots using "Show" command? I tried and edited all five codes but couldn't see any change.

Since your code can't be run, I cannot say for sure. Please include a minimal working example.

I have updated the code. I am changing q values here, as shown in the graph. For all q values, then at the end i am using:  Show[q10Vl, q50Vl, q100Vl, q1000Vl, q10000Vl, PlotRange -> All]

Please can you help me with this?

I can include a general example that I hope you can modify to suit your needs. You can take the Site Tour by clicking the ? sign on the page banner and learn what a Minimal Working Example implies.
In the following, you can change cols to include preferred colors. If you don't need Callout or Tooltip you can make changes accordingly. In place of {x, 2x, 3x ...} you can substitute values from your plots. Learn about the MapThread function from documentation by clicking F1. Remember that all lists used with MapThread should have the same length.
You want an Automatic method of combining legends; I am not familiar with it but then again, my knowledge of plotting requires much improvement.

Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
qvals = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
qlabels = "q = " <> ToString@# & /@ qvals;
lglabels = "q" <> ToString@# <> " (N)" & /@ qvals;
cols = RandomColor[Length@lglabels];
legend = LineLegend[cols, lglabels
   , LegendMarkers -> None
   , LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}
   ];

Legended[
 Show@MapThread[
   Plot[Callout[Tooltip[#1], #2]
     , {x, 0, 20000}
     , Frame -> True
     , FrameLabel -> {
       Style["x (or Time), s", Italic]
       , Style["z(or Volume of liquid), cc", Italic]
       }
     , ImageSize -> 400
     , PlotStyle -> #3
     , PlotRange -> {0, 100000}
     , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
     ] &,
   {{x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x}
    , qlabels
    , cols
    }]
 , Placed[legend, Below]
 ]




Thank you so much, Sir. Its working now.

I am glad to hear it. You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, if it has met your needs. @IshaArora
